# UIImagePickerController - Let user choose between camera and album?

Tags: swift

In my app I have the ability for the user to take a photo and post it to a web service. I use the following code:

```
imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, I would prefer to give the user the option to either take a photo with their camera or pick a photo from the album. I know I can choose `sourceType = .PhotoLibrary` but that again rules out the camera as a possible source. Is there no combination here that can give me both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UIAlertController` to present an alert with style `UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet`, giving those both as choices.

This is like how Apple does it when you choose to add a photo to a text message in the Messages app, and is used in other apps as well to provide this choice, so this is obviously the most official method available for doing this. But you won't find a way to just present a `UIImagePickerController` that lets you choose.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose that is the best way of accomplishing this. Cheers!